# InAppBrowser headers / cookies

Tags: cordova, childbrowser, inappbrowser

How can I send a header when opening a url in the InAppBrowser? Or is it possible to set-cookie value in the InAppBrowser from the parent browser?

Which would you recommend - InAppBrowser or the childBrowser plugin ?

Answer (score 1):

InAppbrowser is just like opening a window using window.open. Once, called its a different window. So anything you cannot do in a window.open cannot be done in the InAppBrowser. InAppBroswer is recommended as it comes out of the box with PhoneGap.

Answer (score 0):

While I've not been able to affect the InAppBrowser headers or cookies directly, I was able to work around the missing Tomcat JSESSIONID cookie by injecting

> ;JSESSIONID=sessionid.jvmroute?

into the url. Beware that this work around exposes the session id that would otherwise be protected by SSL/TLS.